# Is there a way to Avoid the White Flash with React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am using React Native on Android and I am trying to figure out how to avoid the white flash before the React Native Portion of the app starts

The only way I have been able to stop it is by setting the app theme background color, to the same color of my app splashscreen, the issue with that is if you open up the keyboard, you'll briefly see the background of the app near the keyboard...in my scenario creating a blue flash at the bottom of the page

A solution to this would be somehow changing the apps theme color from blue back to white after the app loaded, but that dosen't seem possible. If the background color was white, you wouldn't see a flash..

any ideas?

Comment: Actually you can change it after JS loading, at least I saw in iOS part, that bridge fire events for JS loading (don't know much about android bridge), so, in theory you can somehow listen for bridge events, but you need to dive into android bridge source code

Answer (score 3):

Please try [react-native-splash-screen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen)

Here is an article may also help [How to Add a Splash Screen to a React Native App](https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae)

Answer (score 1):

if you're building an app for ios only, you may use the `loadingView` functionality as described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#pro-tip), otherwise you'll need a splash screen library that will allow to control hiding the splash image from JS